# Spring-rest sub resource request on missing parent

Tags: rest, spring-boot

I have a **User** entity and a **Post** entity with a *One User to Many Posts* relationship. To get a user resource I make a `GET` request to this endpoint in the **UserController**:

```
http://localhost:8080/users/{userId}
```

If the requested `userId` does not correspond to a user in MySQL I throw an exception with a 404 User not found error through the **UserService** class (code below).

```
public User getUser(Integer id) throws ResourceNotFoundException{
    return userRepository.findById(id).map(user -> {
        return user;
    }).orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("User with the ID " + id + " is not available"));
}
```

Now in order to get a **Post** resource I use this endpoint on the **PostController**:

```
http://localhost:8080/users/{userId}/posts/{postId}
```

**My question**: What if I request a Post (whatever this is) on a non existing User? Is the best logic to throw a 404 User not found error again, or Post not found? If so, how can I combine the UserService `getUser(id)` and the PostService `getPost(id)` to throw the error?

Answer (score 0):

Actually it depends how do you map the relationship between user and post.

If it is bidirectional relationship and cascade type is ALL then while deleting the user all the posts created by the user also will get deleted.

So if above is the case then you just check for user in DB if not found then show user not found.

Also you should perform the recommended approach to delete a user using [soft delete](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/10329/whats-the-best-way-to-handle-deleted-user-accounts-on-a-social-app)

Comment: Yes actually it's bidirectional and already have a CascadeType.ALL like so: In the User.class
`@JsonIgnore
 @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user")
 private List<Post> posts;`
In the Post.class
`@ManyToOne
 @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
 private User user;`

Comment: yes..then you can easily check user first if not found return user not found otherwise you need to find post then. if post not found then show post not found.